# Database - Making media gallery for a Laravel project (structure approach)

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I know question is not so clear, I'll try to demonstrate this..

**Main problem:**
I'm trying to make a media gallery for all media that I have in my website. I have 3 types of media *Image* & *Video* & *Slider* .. The *Slider* media have some images within it.

**What I want to do**
how to make a model that can contain these objects in my database so that -> If I want to use a media in a widget or in a post from the blog or any part of my website, I just give this *website part* the id of the media object

**What I've tried**

`Media` table that have (`id`, `media_type`, `id_in_type_table`)

`image` table that have (`id`, `path`)

`Video` table that have (`id`, `path`)

`Slider` table that have (`id`, `path_img_1`, `path_img_2`, `path_img_3`)

but I didn't know how to relate them to retrieve the media object properly

**Is** there a better structure for this gallery database? and how to relate tables?

**Edit ==>
After another thought:**
Slider is actually constructed of some images, then we have only 2 types *Videos* & *Images*, although they have same structure then the Structure would be like this...

`Media` table that have (`id`, `type`, `array_of_IDs`)

`type` => for demonstration of type, it will not be used

`array_of_IDs` => can have one or more gallery object

`Gallery` table that have (`id`, `path`)

**however** I don't know exactly how this approach can be implemented by Laravel because I'm new .. any help ?

Comment: Does Slider always have only 3 images?

Comment: No, I want to make it dynamic but I had no idea how to implement that. if you know how can I make this it will be great

Comment: The slider is easy, just have a slider table and a slider images table with the slider id as a foreign key to it. Handling the different media types might be a little tricky, though.  On the database side it's not that hard, the tricky part is identifying the media type you are handling on the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiet way would be to change the DB the following 3 tables

```
media(id,media_type)
media_properties (id,prop_name)//in your case path.
media_to_properties ('media_id','prop_id','val')
```

then you will have 2 models and they would roughly look like:

```
class MediaProperty extends Eloquent{
      $table = media_properties
      $filleable = array('prop_name');
}

class Media extends Eloquent{
    $table = $media
    public function mediaProperties(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('MediaProperty','media_to_properties', 'media_id', 'prop_id')->withPivot('val');
    }
}
```

when you call your model with id just add with (mediaProperties) , this will allow you to extend your media objects with more properties besides path.

written in  laravel 4.2